# Twitter-bootstrap issues scaling to 13inch screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter-bootstrap for a website I'm making. It wasn't until today that I looked at the website on my 13 inch macbook and saw that it looks horrible there. Especially the first section, the rest is fine. The top section text falls width gets a lot smaller so the text collapses and pushes the rest down. This makes that some text falls below the fold.

There is not much text so I don't really get why this is happening.
I created a new stylesheet for the smaller desktop screen although I'm not sure if that's really necessery since this is the only code that's in there;

```
.containerdiv {
          padding-left:5% !important;
          text-align:left;
          padding-top:4%;
      }
```

I also changed my index a bit from this;

```
<div class="containerdiv hidden-sm hidden-xs visible-md visible-lg">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 logo">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7"><img src="css/images/logo.png" class="float">
            <h1 style="padding-top:84px; padding-left:10px;" class="logotitle">KONIJNTJES</h1>
            <h2 class="sublogo">Nerds zonder grenzen</h2>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 pushleft">

                    <p class="lead">
                        <b>ICT Dienstverlening</b> gecombineerd met<br> <b>Software</b> & <b>Ruimtevaart ontwikkeling.</b>
                    </p>
```

to this;

```
  <div class="containerdiv hidden-sm hidden-xs visible-md visible-lg">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 logo">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7"><img src="css/images/logo.png" class="float">
            <h1 style="padding-top:84px; padding-left:10px;" class="logotitle">KONIJNTJES</h1>
            <h2 class="sublogo">Nerds zonder grenzen</h2>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 pushleft">

                    <p class="lead">
                        <b>ICT Dienstverlening</b> gecombineerd met<br> <b>Software</b> & <b>Ruimtevaart ontwikkeling.</b>
                    </p>
```

This is not really doing anything though. The empty div disappears on mobile devices but not on the 13 inch screen. Also I can't seem to make the divs a little wider so that the text won't get pushed down anymore. What would be the best solution to have the content on the first section appear neatly instead of broken off and pushed down?

My full code is here, in case that helps; http://kellyvuijst.nl/FINAL

Comment: The key is resolution, not size. What resolution is causing problems?

Comment: 1280x800 is the one I'm using on my 13inch macbook and is the one that's causing trouble.